# Using ExtJS with multiple select

Tags: javascript, extjs, html-select, multiple-select

I have a form with next code:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="something" class="boo" name="foo">
    <option value="40">AAAAA</option>
    <option value="39">BBBBB</option>
    <option value="15">CCCCC</option>
</select>
```

Currently this form has a binded onChange function, which looks like:

```
var updateValues = function(event, target, object){
     var selectbox = Ext.get(target.id);
     var values = [];
     for(i=0; i<selectbox.dom.options.length; i++){
         if (selectbox.dom.options[i].selected)
            {values.push(selectbox.dom.options[i].value);}
     }
     callSomeFunc(values);
}
```

I think there should be a function, which returns an array of selected values, just like jQuery's `val()` does.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you actually used Ext components instead of plain HTML form.

Comment: Seems that there is no native ExtJS function that deals with multiple selects. Using Ext components would be quite an overhead for a large number of use cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple selection combined with ComboBox-like functionality, I would recommend using the [SuperBoxSelect](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?69307-3.x-Ext.ux.form.SuperBoxSelect&highlight=superboxselect) user extension. If the out-of-the-box look and feel doesn't suit you, you can easily change it by modifying or removing the included CSS.

The component provides great methods to retrieve the selected values. As the user selects values the component will remember the values and store them internally. Conversely, if a user removes values the component will handle that state for you as well. All you need to do, assuming the original functionality suits you, is call the methods to get the values once you're ready to submit your form.

Here's a demo page if you're interested. It's very easy to include in your javascript, so don't worry that it's a user extension:

http://www.technomedia.co.uk/SuperBoxSelect/examplesRemote.html